# When we look at a 2D diagram of an electromagnetic wave, are we looking at the magnetic fields or the electrical fields?

Tags: magnetic-fields

[image]

This photo above a 3D representation of an electromagnetic wave with electric and magnetic fields shown. However, in an ordinary diagram of a 2D wave... say the electromagnetic spectrum diagram,  what waves are shown in it? The electric or magnetic?

Comment: Can you show an example of one of these 2D diagrams? More context?

Comment: Usually it just means 'whichever component is physically more important in the given situation', which is often the electric field.

Comment: Yes, the state of the electromagnetic field is represented by it's polarization direction and hence it will be the electric field.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a 2D wave diagram which supposedly is also an "electromagnetic spectrum diagram" ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In 2-D only the electric field is shown....the amplitude of the electric field $E$ is related to the amplitude of the magnetic field $B$ by a factor of $c$ (the speed of light), as in $E = cB$. The magnetic field component of an electromagnetic field is so tiny that it's not shown in 2-D. This also shows that 3-D diagrams of electromagnetic fields are not drawn to scale.

Comment: The relationship you quote for E- and B-fields is true only for vacuum. Additionally, even for vacuum, the energy density in the wave is shared equally between electric and magnetic fields, your dismissal of the B-field is likely only useful when considering the Lorentz force.